# SimpleCursorAdapter java exibir imagens

Tags: java, android

Como eu faço para exibir a imagens no layout com SimpleCursorAdapter?
Meu código .java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listarordens);

    SQLiteDatabase db   = openOrCreateDatabase("ordens.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    ListView ltwLocais  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listHist);
    Cursor cursor       = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ordens ORDER BY _id ASC",null);

    String[] from = {"_id","numero","descricao","datahora","foto"};
    int[] to = {R.id.textId, R.id.textNumero, R.id.textDescricao,R.id.textDatahora,R.id.textFoto};



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.model_listar, cursor, from, to);

    ltwLocais.setAdapter(ad);
    db.close();


}
```

e meu .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNumero"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDescricao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNumero"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.77"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDatahora"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textFoto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDatahora"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textNumero"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textFoto"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textFoto"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Especifica mais um bocado o que queres, eu não vou olhar para o teu código a não ser que saiba o que é para fazer e qual é o teu problema.

Comment: Você teve algum erro? O que aconteceu quando implementou o código ai a cima? Encontrou alguma dificuldade?

Comment: eu quero exibir a imagem a partir da url (foto), do bd

Comment: No TextView textFoto queres que apareça a URL da imagem e ao clicares nela apareça a imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para aparecer a foto, você precisa trocar o TextView por uma ImageView.

Se o Bitmap da imagem estiver salvo no banco, acredito que irá funcionar. O layout ficaria assim:

```
//Restante do layout...
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textDatahora"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Small Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageFoto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textDatahora"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textNumero"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

E na sua classe, altere o id do elemento:

```
int[] to = {R.id.textId, R.id.textNumero, R.id.textDescricao,R.id.textDatahora,R.id.imageFoto};
```

Outra alternativa é usar o `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`, o link a seguir pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510335/simplecursoradapter-with-imageview-and-textview